# Prove that $\displaystyle \sum_{cyc} \dfrac {1}{\sqrt{a+2b+3c+10}} \leq 1$ for $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{R}^+$ which satisfies $abcd=1$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Prove that $\displaystyle \sum_{cyc} \dfrac {1}{\sqrt{a+2b+3c+10}} \leq 1$ for $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{R}^+$ which satisfies $abcd=1$.$\Big($$\displaystyle \sum_{cyc}$ is for 4-variables.$\Big)$

\begin{align}
&\text{let } a = \frac y x, b = \frac z y, c = \frac w z, d= \frac x w. \\
& \Rightarrow \text{ETS) } \displaystyle \sum_{cyc} \frac {\sqrt{xyzw}}{\sqrt{y^2zw+2z^2wx+3w^2xy+10xyzw}} \leq 1.
\end{align}

I was thinking about the best expression to use the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality.

Comment: Is it allowed to have also negative values among $a,b,c,d$?

Comment: It should be Baltic Way 2018, Problem 3:  https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1734182p11252365

Comment: @ReneSchipperus No, the original F.E. is the correct form.

Comment: @RiverLi Okay, I'll look for it.

Comment: @dan_fulea Sorry, I'll change it. It isn't allowed.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus : in cyclic sum $\sum_{cyc} a = a+b+c+d$. The typo is not obvious.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu Oh,  I see what you mean ! So I was wrong, there is no typo. OP should make it explicit.

Comment: Sorry, but its a peeve of mine. "Proof" is a noun. It means a demonstration that some statement is true. "Prove" is a verb. It means to produce a proof.  You cannot "proof" something in mathematics. Instead you "prove" it.

Comment: Note that if $a = b = c = d$, then all four are $1$, and the sum is $4\frac 1{\sqrt{16}} = 1$, the maximum value. So if you can show that making them non-equal decreases the value, you are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us generalize once for all times this inequality.

We fix some $n\ge 2$.

Let $a=(1,2,\dots,(n-1),N)$ with $N=\frac 12n(n-1)$, so the sum of the components is $n^2$.

Let $x=(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ be a tuple of positive numbers so that their product is one.

The group of permutations acts on the components of $x$, and we let below
only the subgroup $C$ generated by the cycle $(123\dots n)$ act, sums will be built
below over it, we write a "$x$-cyclic" attribute under the sums.
So the $a$-coefficients are kept in place,
and we build the scalar products of the $a$ vector with each of the $n$
cyclically permuted $x$ vectors.

Then we have the inequalities:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\left(
\sum_{x\text{-cyclic}} \frac 1{\sqrt{x_1+2x_2+\dots + (n-1)x_{n-1}+N}}
\right)^2
\\
&\qquad\le
n
\sum_{x\text{-cyclic}} \frac 1{x_1+2x_2+\dots + (n-1)x_{n-1}+N}
\\
&\qquad\le 1\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
The first inequality is Cauchy-Schwarz.

Let us show the second one.
It is convenient to replace the variables $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$
by $y_1^n,y_2^n,\dots,y_n^n$ with positive $y_1,y_2,\dots, y_n$ of product also one.

We have:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&x_1+2x_2+3x_3+\dots + (n-1)x_{n-1}+N
\\[3mm]
&\qquad=\;y_1^n+2y_2^n+3y_3^n+\dots + (n-1)y_{n-1}^n+N
\\[3mm]
&\qquad=\; (y_1^n+y_2^n+y_3+\dots + y_{n-1}^n+1)\\
 &\qquad\qquad +(  1+y_2^n+y_3^n+\dots + y_{n-1}^n+1)\\
 &\qquad\qquad\qquad +(  1+1+y_3^n+\dots + y_{n-1}^n+1)\\
 &\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad + \dots \\
 &\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad +(  1+1+1+\dots + 1+1)
\\[3mm]
& \qquad \ge \; n(y_1^n\cdot y_2^n \cdot y_3\cdot  \dots \cdot y_{n-1}^n \cdot 1)^{1/n}\\
 &\qquad\qquad +n(  1\cdot y_2^n \cdot y_3^n \cdot \dots \cdot  y_{n-1}^n\cdot 1)^{1/n}\\
 &\qquad\qquad\qquad +n(  1 \cdot 1 \cdot y_3^n\cdot  \dots \cdot  y_{n-1}^n \cdot 1)^{1/n}\\
 &\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad + \dots \\
 &\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad +n(  1\cdot 1\cdot 1 \cdot \dots \cdot  1\cdot 1)^{1/n}
\\[3mm]
& \qquad =n\cdot y_1y_2y_3\dots y_{n-1}\
 +\ n\cdot y_2y_3\dots y_{n-1}\
 +\ n\cdot y_3\dots y_{n-1}\
 +\ \dots\  +\  n
\\[3mm]
& \qquad =: n\; P(y_1,y_2,\dots,y_n)\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
The last line is a definition of $P$. It does not depend on $y_n$, but soon
we act cyclically, and observe that multipication by $y_n$ brings...
$$
(y_1y_2y_3\dots y_{n-1}\
 +\ y_2y_3\dots y_{n-1}\
 +\ \dots\  +\  1)
\overset{\cdot y_n}\longrightarrow
(1\
 +\ y_2y_3\dots y_{n-1}y_n\
 +\ \dots\  +\  y_n)
$$
so
$$
P(y_1,y_2,\dots,y_n)
\overset{\cdot y_n}\longrightarrow
P(y_2,\dots,y_n,y_1)
\overset{\cdot y_1}\longrightarrow
P(y_3,\dots,y_1,y_2)
\overset{\cdot y_2}\longrightarrow
\dots\qquad .
$$
So
$$
\begin{aligned}
&n\sum_{x\text{-cyclic}} \frac 1{x_1+2x_2+\dots + (n-1)x_{n-1}+N}
\\
&\qquad =
n\sum_{y\text{-cyclic}} \frac 1{y_1^n+2y_2^n+\dots + (n-1)y_{n-1}^n+N}
\\
&\qquad\le
n\sum_{y\text{-cyclic}} \frac 1{n\cdot P(y_1,y_2,\dots,y_n)}
\\
&\qquad =
\frac 1{P(y_1,y_2,\dots,y_n)}
+
\frac 1{P(y_2,y_3,\dots,y_1)}
+
\dots
+
\frac 1{P(y_n,y_1,\dots,y_{n-1})}
\\
&\qquad =
\frac 1{P(y_1,y_2,\dots,y_n)}
+
\frac 1{y_n\;P(y_1,y_2,\dots,y_n)}
+
\dots
+
\frac 1{y_ny_1\dots y_{n-2}\; P(y_1,y_2,\dots,y_n)}
\\
&\qquad =
\frac 1{P(y_1,y_2,\dots,y_n)}\left[
1+\frac 1{y_n}+\dots+\frac 1{y_ny_1\dots y_{n-2}}
\right]
\\
&\qquad =
\frac 1{P(y_1,y_2,\dots,y_n)}
\left[
1+y_1y_2\dots y_{n-1}+\dots+y_{n-1}
\right]
\\
&\qquad =
\frac {P(y_1,y_2,\dots,y_n)}{P(y_1,y_2,\dots,y_n)}
\\
&\qquad =
1\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
$\square$

---

As in the AoPS link added in the comments,
[Hard cyclic inequality with square roots](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1734182p11252365),
we have the following instances of this generalization:
$$
\begin{aligned}
1 &\ge \frac 1{\sqrt{x+3}} + \frac 1{\sqrt{y+3}}\ , \qquad xy=1\ ,\ x,y> 0\ ,\\
1 &\ge \frac 1{\sqrt{x+2y+6}} + \frac 1{\sqrt{y+2z+6}}+ \frac 1{\sqrt{z+2x+6}}\ ,\qquad xyz=1\ ,\ x,y,z> 0\ ,\\
1 &\ge 
\frac 1{\sqrt{x+2y+3z+10}} 
+\frac 1{\sqrt{y+2z+3t+10}} 
+\frac 1{\sqrt{z+2t+3x+10}} 
+\frac 1{\sqrt{t+2x+3y+10}}\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
where in the last case $ xyzt=1$, $x,y,z,t> 0$.